# Running time of program

Tags: linux, shell, time

I have a program which I run by command:

```
time ./my-program.sh
```

output is:

> ./my-program.sh  10,31s user 8,13s system 38% cpu 47,308 total

but I don't know, why total time is so long when the system and user time is so short..

Do you anybody know how can I determine why my program takes so long?

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
FILE=message.tb

mysql -uroot -ptest --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -e 'select * from
message;' mydatabase > $FILE

cat $FILE |  while read; do ./my-program; done
```

`./my-program` is written in C and it transfers the data from my database and saves it.

Comment: Does it wait for something? If so it might be idle time.

Comment: Hmm maybe there is waiting than data are load or save on disk..

Comment: Let it run once without the last line and time it. Does it show a similar pattern? If not it's the `program` (most likely) to debug what's happening there you'd have to do some in depth stuff. Also check this one: [What do 'real', 'user' and 'sys' mean in the output of time(1)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556405/what-do-real-user-and-sys-mean-in-the-output-of-time1)

Comment: Would this stream flow at about the same rate that text scrolls on the screen?  If $FILE is particularly long, I can see that easily taking 30s.